# How to get the ViewBag from the view? always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In the controller, I do a ViewBag, which I later transmit to the view, fill in the data there and want to send it in a post request, but the viewbag returns null how to return the selected data from the ViewBag

Comment: Could you add some detail about that post request? From where, how?

Comment: Please do not write code in comments, it is hard to read. Edit it into your question

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the html look good in your browser? Also add these details to your question

Comment: after I send the form I receive Data - null

Comment: have you tried debugging to see whether you get any data back in this call `var e = manager.Get();`?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but AFAIK this is not how the ViewBag variable was meant to be used.  It is for sharing small amounts of data from the Controller to the view (on the client), not the other way around.

To get data back to the server you'll need to explicitly post back the data you need in a request to your server from your client view.

Lets break this down

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.List)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                        }
```

In the above code, ViewBag should exist as a dynamic variable, and if you set List in the view bag object when the view is being requested by the client it will contain whatever data you put there.

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="action">
                        Submit
                    </button>
```

Here, in the html above, you are now trying to Post back whatever options you select.   it is here youll need to specify an endpoint that will recieve the form data and do whatever is required with it

Comment: How can I do it ?

Comment: I want to send the id of the selected item, I get the name I entered, but Data = null

Comment: if you intend to stick with web api and mvc, then you wont be using ViewBag to read the data back in.   Rather, the data will be accessible as an object passed in as an argument to the post back method you create to handle the form.  But really, forms can be handled any number of a thousand ways, and each method can be considered correct.   its tough to shoe horn your question in to an issuewith mvc when its a lack of understanding about https, html, and web standards.

Comment: OK, how can I transfer the selected data from the view to the controller?

Comment: https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/3-ways-to-receive-data-from-postbacks-in-aspnet-mvc-C2   some light reading

Comment: Rahul, he was asking why viewbag was null when he tried to access it after a round trip to the client and back, i believe i gave a pretty good answer for that question

Answer (score 0):

I would take bigger amount of data from MODEL

MODEL

```
 public string Name{ get; set; }
```

VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<*YourProjectName*.Models.*ModelName*>
```

Code above, between * * change it to right project name and Model name.
It should do it automatically after you write @model

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```